# use window.open in an electron app

Tags: electron, window.open

I'm attempting to open a window from an electron app. Trying to have this opened window node-integration set to false.

```
const MyButton = (props: any) => {
    return props.url ? <a className="my-btn" onClick={() => {
        let win = window.open("http://www.google.com/", "_blank", "toolbar=yes,scrollbars=yes,resizable=yes,top=500,left=500,width=400,height=400");
        console.log('Is open: ' + !win.closed);
    }} target="_blank">My Button</a> : null;
};
```

Issue is that i don't see the window pop up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution that works is to 'intercept' window.open() calls in the preload script. In the preload script you could create a new browser window and open it.